# Install libtensorflow universal binary via Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, tensorflow2.0, macos-catalina

Until some weeks ago, in my Macbook with Intel processor I have always installed `libtensorflow` via Homebrew. Now, if possible I would need the universal binary of the same library and so I have tried to build it from scratch but I am facing the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77406226/ld-error-while-trying-to-build-macos-universal-binary-libtensorflow) explained.
In the meantime I was thinking to some workarounds, and I was wondering if it is possible to tell Homebrew to install the universal binary build of the a certain formula. By doing a web search I found nothing but the `--universal-binary` option but it seems to be related to the 32 and/or 64 bit version of the same formula, not to the processo family.
Are there any suggestion with this regard? Is this possible and, if yes, how?